# Whats the easiest way to plot two dataframes onto a single plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

df1 has two columns, column 1 'key' with 20 items. Column 2 'df1_val' with values against each key.

df2 is similar but column 2 is called df2_val.

Whats the easiest way to plot a single plot with both df1_val and df2_val - x-axis assigned to keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

Start by naming your df_1value and df_2value as the same 'value', then

```
fig = plt.figure()

for r in [df_1,df_2]:
    plt.plot(r['key'], r['value'])

plt.xlim(0,<a value>)
plt.ylim(0,<a value >)
plt.show()
```

An alternativ is to do this. Plot what you need for first dataframe df1 and use `ax` to "force" the other plots in the same graph

````
ax = df.plot() 
```
And 

```
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```
````